# Qt How to update GUI in the loop

Tags: qt

I need to update screen to show how button is moving.
Here is my code:

```
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    double b=(button->x()*event->y())/(button->x()-1);
    double k=(button->y()-b)/button->x();
    int time=0;
    fnl=false;
    if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        while(!fnl)
        {
            int mX=button->x()-1;
            int mY=k*(button->x()-1)+b;
            button->setText(QString::number(b));
            button->move(mX,mY);
            QThread::sleep(1);
            //here I need to update screen and show button
        }

    }
}
```

But it does not update GUI. It simply plays inside the loop.

Comment: Do you know QTimer? I would advice you to create a fuction periodically called by a timer. In the function, you can check whether the button is pressed and if yes, update its position.

Comment: Is there any event handler like `timer1.tick` as in C# timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never use `QThread::sleep()` in the GUI thread**, It will block the GUI thread from doing anything. Instead, You can use `QTimer` to schedule something to run at a later point in time. Also, Your slots/functions should be as short and optimized as possible in order to return control to the event loop and be able to handle [other events that may happen](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#What_requires_a_running_event_loop.3F).

You may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41198051/2666212) for a similar problem.
The same technique can be applied here to solve the problem by replacing your while loop with a slot and a `QTimer` whose interval is set to `0`. **But Qt can do all that job using [the animation framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html)**, Here is an example of a button that gets moved when clicked:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //create and show button
    QPushButton button("Animated Button");
    button.move(QPoint(100, 100));
    button.show();
    //create property animator object that works on the position of the button
    QPropertyAnimation animation(&button, "pos");
    //set duration for the animation process to 500ms
    animation.setDuration(500);

    //when the button is clicked. . .
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
        //set the starting point of the animation to the current position
        animation.setStartValue(button.pos());
        //set the ending point to (250, 250)
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 250));
        //start animation
        animation.start();
    });

    return a.exec();
}
```

Qt also provides [many examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-animation.html) for using the animation framework. . .

Comment: Thanks. The exact thing I have been looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A timer is the best option. If you want to use brute force you can call

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

inside your loop. Ugly but gets the job done.

Comment: When using `processEvents()`, Your code should be [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)), this means that you should be prepared to have the same event that got you into this slot delivered again. In this situation, the slot is called again within itself (and this may happen infinitely in some situations). and most likely this is not the behavior you want. Take a look at [this page from the wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Forcing_event_dispatching)

Comment: @Mike -- Agreed. I should have said "Ugly but often gets the job done"...

Comment: The point is to do the job right. When you get in the habit of writing asynchronous code, it opens up many other possibilities and makes life much easier. The next step up is to get in the habit of [using state machines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37667951/1329652).